# Issue in Rest service Domino API for Decline

Tags: lotus-domino

Problem scenario:-

Organiser sends a meeting request to attendee for 17th Oct. Attendee accepts the request. Organiser Reschedules the meeting to 18th Oct. Attendee sees 2 meetings, one on 17th(original) and another on 18th(Rescheduled). The get meetings api : http://{host}/{filenamepath}/api/calendar/events , also gives 2 events. Till this, it is valid.

Now, Attendee declines the rescheduled meeting using http://{host}/{filenamepath}/api/calendar/notices/{noticeid}/action?type=decline. Both the meetings are removed from the attendee’s calendar, which is also right.

But the get meetings api still gives me a response with 1 event, i.e. the Rescheduled meeting. Am I wrong on the api call for declining the notice?

Comment: What version of Domino?  I tried to reproduce your problem, but I see different results.  For example, after the organizer reschedules, there is only one event in the response from "GET /{db}/api/calendar/events".  Perhaps we are using different versions.

Comment: I could reproduce the scenario in both versions, 8.5.3 and 9.0.1.

Comment: The scenario is specific to Attendee. After organiser reschedules, there should be 2 events in the response from "GET /{db}/api/calendar/events" for attendee; one the old accepted event and the other would be the Rescheduled invite.   The issue now lies in decline meeting.

Comment: 8.5.3?  The REST calendar service isn't available with 8.5.3.  And please be specific about the version of 9.0.1.  Do you have a 9.0.1 fix pack installed?  Are you using the extension library from OpenNTF?

Comment: it is 9.0.1 version , we aren't using extension library from OpenNTF.